# how to open new page in same tab on clicking any option of drop down menu in html

Tags: html

I have a drop down list. I have links in each option, when user changes option I want to open new page in same tab. but here page opens in new tab.

```
<html>
   <body>
      <form name="opennew">
         <select name="sites" id="sites">
            <option value="" selected>Select Site</option>
            <option value="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo!!!</option>
            <option value="http://www.gmail.com">Gmail</option>
            <option value="http://www.google.co.in">Google</option>
            <option value="http://www.facebook.com">Facebook</option>
         </select>

         <input type="button" name="Submit" value="Go!" onClick="window.open(sites.value)">
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ChU8G/)**

Answer (score 1):

Add `_parent` in `onClick` like this:

```
onClick="window.open(sites.value, '_parent')"
```

The chosen site would be opened in parent frame which is the same window/tab.

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vule/p4W6v/)**